# Is a damaged charging cable safe to use?

Tags: battery-charging, damage

I have a M1 Macbook Pro 2021, 14". The charger that comes with this device is the 67W adapter and a USB-C to MagSafe3 adapter. Unfortunately, today I didn't see the charger on the ground and hit it with my boots. The result now is that the USB-C part of the cable is slightly bent (I will attach pictures below.) There is no visble damage to the adapter.

[image]

A picture of the adapter can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r8xV.jpg) and a close-up picture of the port can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHlmj.jpg).

The Macbook is still charging fine, as far as I can tell, i.e. the speed seems reasonable and the indication light on the cable is still on.

Can I continue to use this bent cable without any worry that my Macbook/the battery will be damaged from it?

Comment: This type of Power Supply normally has a short circuit protection. Guess it is still safe, as long as it works. It should not be dangerous, but I would not suggest to assume its reliable any more: there might be some (pre-) damage which can cause to misfunction any time

Comment: We can't know if there is mechanical damage which will grind and damage the connector in laptop. This is more suitable question for manufacturer service/repair department.

Comment: It is better NOT to use the bent adapter. But, since it charges just fine its up to you to decide if you want to risk it. Worse case scenario would be a short on the bented adapter and your charging circuit will get fried (althought these charging circuits are supposed to have short-circuit protection)

Answer (score 1):

This type of damage is all too common with charging leads. I would suggest that you use the cable as little as possible until you can replace it. You never know how long it will be before it shorts, goes open circuit or damages the socket on your Macbook.
Shorting or going open circuit are not, in themselves, a problem as the charger and Macbook are probably protected against this, but, of course, you will end up with a flat battery.

Comment: Would you just replace the cable, or also the adapter that is used with it? The adapter shows no visible sign of damage, but of course there could be something broken that I cannot see right now...

Comment: The adaptor **looks** OK, so try replacing the cable first. This should prevent any short or open problems. It's also a lot cheaper. Monitor the performance and only replace the adaptor if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Got it, but just to be sure: The picture that is included in the post is the connection between the adapter and the cable... This side of the cable is thus never plugged into the Mac itself, only into the adapter. (I was a bit confused by your sentence: "or damages the socket on your Macbook.", which in this scenario cannot really happen, right?). Monitoring performance here means looking at the charging speed, correct? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: My mistake, it should have looked more closely at the pictures and said "socket in the charger". Monitoring is simpler than that, either it will charge as normal or it won't charge at all. As to damaging the socket in the Macbook, you could apply excessive loads to that end of the cable (trip over the wire) and cause similar damage. It's also worth keeping an eye on the so called strain relief at either end of the cable. I've seen several genuine Apple parts where the cable outer breaks and the inner wires fray at the relief after a few years use.